# Is there a way to read test data from XLS for a Gherkin (cucumber-jvm) feature file ?

Tags: cucumber-jvm

I would like have layered design for tests and test data , looking for any option to read test data from XLS or any other files .

If there is any API available in cucumber jvm please let me know.

Comment: Cucumber - ruby has annotation option of reading the XLS files and fields directly @@file name , just looking for something similar to that !

Answer (score 1):

Using Apache POI you should be able to Read data from an XLS file
All you need to do is add the logic to your Feature steps definitions.

Apache POI- http://poi.apache.org/

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, even i am trying that too . i thought there is some direct cucumber API support.like it has for ruby version @@file and can access the fields of XLS file directly ...

Comment: As of now i have achieved this using POI only , but loosing the data-provider feature .i mean same test feature with multiple sets of data.